# webkitmutationobserver does not work in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit

I need to monitor the display state of an element. I'm using the following code

```
if WebKitMutationObserver?
    observer = new WebKitMutationObserver observerFunc
    observer.observe el, {attributes:true}
  else
    el.addEventListener "DOMAttrModified",(event)->
      wrapper.style.display = el.style.display
      return
```

However this does not work in Safari.

Also, typing "WebKitMutationObserver" in developer tools immediate window in Chrome gives the output

```
function WebKitMutationObserver() { [native code] }
```

while in Safari (v 5.1.7), this gives an error with the message
    "Can't find variable: WebKitMutationObserver"

Could it be that Safari does not support WebkitMutationObserver? And if so, is there an alternative which I could use for this?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be in Safari 5.1.7 (Snow Leopard); I get `undefined` for `window.WebKitMutationObserver`

Comment: Thanks for checking @Flambino. It seems Safari really does not support either WebkitMutationObserver or DOMAttrModified. I wonder if there is any way to accomplish the same behavior without resorting to a window.setInterval (which would get really ugly for the numerous elements I have on the page).

Answer (score 0):

The newest Safari (6.0) does include `WebKitMutationObserver`. For older Safari's, here's some code we have used that fakes a `DOMAttrModified` event when you use `setAttribute` or `removeAttribute` to change an attribute. Note that this doesn't work if the browser itself changes an attribute internally.

```
  var win = window;
  var doc = win.document;
  var attrModifiedWorks = false;
  var listener = function () { attrModifiedWorks = true; };
  doc.documentElement.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", listener, false);
  doc.documentElement.setAttribute("___TEST___", true);
  doc.documentElement.removeAttribute("___TEST___", true);
  doc.documentElement.removeEventListener("DOMAttrModified", listener, false);
  if (!attrModifiedWorks)
  {
    This.DOMAttrModifiedUnsupported = true;

    win.HTMLElement.prototype.__setAttribute = win.HTMLElement.prototype.setAttribute;
    win.HTMLElement.prototype.setAttribute = function fixDOMAttrModifiedSetAttr (attrName, newVal)
    {
      var prevVal = this.getAttribute(attrName);
      this.__setAttribute(attrName, newVal);
      newVal = this.getAttribute(attrName);
      if (newVal != prevVal)
      {
        var evt = doc.createEvent("MutationEvent");
        evt.initMutationEvent
          ( "DOMAttrModified"
          , true
          , false
          , this
          , prevVal || ""
          , newVal || ""
          , attrName
          , (prevVal == null) ? win.MutationEvent.ADDITION : win.MutationEvent.MODIFICATION
          );
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
      }
    }

    win.HTMLElement.prototype.__removeAttribute = win.HTMLElement.prototype.removeAttribute;
    win.HTMLElement.prototype.removeAttribute = function fixDOMAttrModifiedRemoveAttr (attrName)
    {
      var prevVal = this.getAttribute(attrName);
      this.__removeAttribute(attrName);
      var evt = doc.createEvent("MutationEvent");
      evt.initMutationEvent("DOMAttrModified", true, false, this, prevVal, "", attrName, win.MutationEvent.REMOVAL);
      this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Erik :) I ended up changing the feature list to avoid having to deal with this stuff completely.

Comment: This depends on jQuery it looks like.

Comment: @jocull: the dependecy was very trivial. I've removed the calls to `bind` and `unbind`, replacing them with `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` and the dependency is now gone.